# Block place event isn't working Minecraft Plugin Java

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a plugin and for some reason my onBlockPlace event does not work. Here is my code:

```java
import org.bukkit.entity.Player; 
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

public class test implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        System.out.println("Test!");
        player.sendMessage("Test");

    }

}
```

Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Make sure you registered the `Listener` class

Comment: @Bernard i just added that but it did not fix my issue, hopefully i added it correctly.

Comment: Please edit the question and add relevant code snippets

Comment: @Bernard this is all in this class, i am could you specify exactly what you need?

Comment: The code where you register the `Listener`s, all `BlockPlaceEvent` handlers, all `PlayerInteractEvent` handlers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bukkit (spigot api) listener not responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866183/bukkit-spigot-api-listener-not-responding)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have all the stuff necessary in the listener class. So in your plugin class (the class that extends `JavaPlugin`) you'll want to use [this function](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/plugin/PluginManager.html#registerEvents(org.bukkit.event.Listener,org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin)). I'll explain the steps but it'll be a mess so you can understand what the code is doing.

1. Create a new instance of your listener using `Listener listener = new test();`
2. Get the server's plugin manager
   `PluginManager manager = getServer.getPluginManager();`
3. Register the listener with the plugin manager `manager.registerEvents(listener, this);`